# Current value of option

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, finance, economics

risk free rate=$r$

volatility of stock price=$\sigma$

continuous dividend rate=$q$

$a>0,K>0$

If your stock price S becomes below $K$ at maturity T,
the option A pays you $aS_T$.
Otherwise, this option pays you zero.

I have to prove that the curret value($v_0$) of this option A is

$v_0=aS_0e^{-qT}\phi(-d)$

where $d=\frac{(ln\frac{S_0}{K}+(r-q+\sigma^2/2))}{\sigma\sqrt{T}}$ and
$\phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of standard normal distribution.

I learned Black-Scholes formula but I can't even figure out how to start.
Any suggestions please?

Comment: You might get an answer here, but it may be worth also trying economics stackexchange or finance stackexchange, but make sure to be transparent that you are posting the question across multiple sites.

Comment: Hint: Write $S_T=S_0e^{(r-q)T+\sigma\sqrt{T}\epsilon-\frac{\sigma^2T}{2}}$ where $\epsilon\sim N(0,1)$ and compute the discounted expectation of the payoff
$$
e^{-rT}aS_T1_{\{S_T<K\}}.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you know how to derive B&s formula, you're halfway there. The basic principle of math. finance is that the price of a contingent claim is just the expctation of discounted payoff, i.e. $\mathbb{E}[e^{-rT}\text{Payoff}]$.

Here $\text{Payoff} = aS_T \mathbb{I}_{\{S_T < K\}}$ and so we have to compute the following, where $z \sim N(mT,\sigma^2 T), m = (r-q-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})$:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[e^{-rT} aS_T \mathbb{I}_{\{S_T < K\}}] &= ae^{-rT} \int_{- \infty}^{+\infty}\frac{S_0 e^{z}e^{-\frac{(z-mT)^2}{2 \sigma^2 T}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2 T}} \mathbb{I}_{\{S_0 e^z < K\}}dz\\ 
&= \text{Substitute} \;  y=\frac{z-mT}{\sigma T} \; \text{and take into account the carachteristic function} \\
&= aS_0e^{-rT}\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{\ln \frac{K}{S_0}-mT}{\sigma T}}e^{mT}\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y^2 -2\sigma \sqrt{T} y)}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}dy \\
&= \text{Complete the square in the exponent} \\
&= aS_0e^{-rT} e^{mT}\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{\ln \frac{K}{S_0}-mT}{\sigma T}}e^{\frac{\sigma^2T}{2}}\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y-\sigma \sqrt{T})^2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}dy \\
&= \text{Substitute} \; t = y-\sigma \sqrt{T} \\
&= aS_0e^{-rT} e^{mT}\int_{-\infty}^{-d}\frac{e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}dt \\
&= \text{Simplify the exponentials and notice the normal CDF} \\
&= aS_0 e^{-qT} \Phi(-d)
\end{align}
$$